# ng-selected not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My problem is that `ng-selected` is set as `true` but the option is not getting selected

This is my controller code

```
.controller("PendingInvoiceCtrl", function($scope, $location, safeApply, dataService) {
    var userData = dataService.data();
    var mauth_token = userData.mauthToken;
    var mauth_acntId = userData.thisApartment.account;
    var apt_id = userData.thisApartment.id;

    $scope.house_list = userData.thisApartment.house;
    $scope.selectedHouseId = $location.search().houseId;

    console.log($scope.selectedHouseId);
});
```

This is my HTML code

```
 <select ng-model="selectedHouseId">
      <option ng-repeat="house in house_list" ng-selected="{{ house.house_id == selectedHouseId }}" value="{{ house.house_id }}">
           {{ house.house_display_name }}
      </option>
 </select>
```

And below is my data format

```
 {
      house:[0]:{
           house_display_name: "paras, 101",
           house_id: "520755"
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ng-` attributes don't need the extra curly braces. Try:

```
<option ng-repeat="house in house_list" ng-selected="house.house_id == selectedHouseId" ng-value="house.house_id">
    {{house.house_display_name}}
</option>
```

A better approach would be to use the `ng-options` possibility of the `select` tag. This would result in:

```
<select
    ng-model="selectedHouseId"
    ng-options="house.house_id as house.house_display_name for house in house_list">
</select>
```

And then you don't need to manually worry about the `selected` attribute for the options, as it will select the one depending on the value of the model.

Answer (score 8):

Your option tag should be:

```
<option ng-repeat="house in house_list" ng-selected="house.house_id == selectedHouseId" ng-value="house.house_id">
```

Comment: It's working but still getting one extra option on the html
<option value="? string:385787 ?"></option>

i can hide using <option value="" hidden></option> but that's hack it want proper solution can yu help

Comment: @SiddharthPandey What do you mean by that? Could you check that the `house_list.length` matches the number of options?

Comment: Lenght is not an issue it don't know why its generating the same

Comment: You will need to initialize the ng-model (selectedHouseId) differently, as its initial  value is not always equivalent to any of the ngOptions, so it adds its own option (usually with a val of ? or 0).

Comment: It looks like it's the data you're receiving from the `dataService`. Make sure it's returning the correct data.

Comment: You are a life saver.  I had just value for 12 hours today when I really needed ng-value.  There were lot's of other things I had to figure out today but that was the last kicker.  Thank you.

Comment: @Sam np, glad to help!

Answer (score 4):

if you use ng-Selected and ng-Model together was never really specified. It looks like at some point ng-Model took priority over ng-Selected.

Comment: I was facing the same problem!
Using ng-Model in select tag and ng-Selected in option tag (with ng-repeat).
Removed ng-Model and everything worked!
Thanks!

Comment: how then do you connect the chosen value?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use the Angular Directive ng-options.

```
<select ng-options="house.house_id as house.house_display_name for house in house_list" ng-model="selectedHouseId"></select>
```

Associated plunker: http://plnkr.co/8LGz5o0d2gDRoRHYr4pQ